# Laravel Controller get limit number item

Tags: php, laravel, model, controller

In my Controller

```
$items = Item::all();
```

I want to get the first 6 items only

How to change the code?

Answer (score 8):

Use [`take()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#retrieving-multiple-models) method:

```
$items = Item::take(6)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `take` function

```
 $items = Item::take(6)->get();
```

Check in laravel docs : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries

Answer (score 0):

To limit the number of results returned from the query you may use the `take()` method.

```
$items = Item::take(6)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

or this

```
$items = Item::paginate(6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `limit()` and pass 'number of records' to limit method.

```
$items = Item::limit(6)->get();
```

Alternatively, you can use `take()` as well.

```
$items = Item::take(6)->get();
```

Use methods which are supported by your Laravel Version.
Hope it helps!