# get limit from Relationship Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

How can i get a limited items from relationship with Laravel

this is my laravel code:

```
 $data = $category->posts;
```

i want something like:

```
 $data = $category->posts->limit(4);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Controller get limit number item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930388/laravel-controller-get-limit-number-item)

Comment: No, it does not, i want to get limit from relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing a relationship like a method (i.e. `$category->posts()`) will give you a query builder, on which you can chain methods:

```php
$firstFourPosts = $category->posts()->take(4)->get();
```

Comment: yes it solved my problem, but i want to get another relation ship from 
`$firstFourPosts`
i was use   
`$data = $category->posts;`
`$data->comments`
but now with your code it is no longer work.

sorry about my English

Answer (score 1):

Define a separate relationship with the limit (or change `posts()`):

```
public function postsLimited() {
    return $this->posts()->limit(4);
}

$data = $category->postsLimited;
```